# How to change the scrollbar color using css

Tags: css

**[My jsfiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/Xck2A/)**
I trying to change the color of the scrollbar but here it is not working.

Css:

```
.flexcroll {     
    scrollbar-face-color: #367CD2;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-highlight-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-track-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #FFFFFF;
}​
```

Comment: this will only work in IE browsers..

Comment: @Suresh Pattu: Are you comfirtable with javascript or jquery solutions?

Comment: I think you should view
[this topic][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890471/scrollbar-color-change-in-firefox

Comment: @Suresh Pattu: By Using jScrollpane a jQuery plugin, you can achieve a cross browser solution See This [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/tRbCs/)

Comment: @Suresh Pattu: I am adding this as answer, So kindly accept it. Otherwise your question will remain open/active.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use the following attributes for webkit, which reach into the *shadow DOM*:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar              { /* 1 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-button       { /* 2 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-track        { /* 3 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece  { /* 4 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb        { /* 5 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner       { /* 6 */ }
::-webkit-resizer                { /* 7 */ }
```

Here's a working fiddle with a red scrollbar, based on code from [this page](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/) explaining the issues.

http://jsfiddle.net/hmartiro/Xck2A/1/

Using this and your solution, you can handle all browsers except Firefox, which at this point I think still requires a javascript solution.

Comment: not a good idea.. it should be cross browser solution.

Comment: There is none - you will have to handle browsers separately, or use a javascript library that handles it for you.

Comment: By handling browsers separately you can't achieve same result.

Comment: So it is better to use javascript/jquery plugins..

Comment: I agree that you can't currently stylize a Firefox scrollbar with CSS, so javascript should be used for full support

Comment: @A.K: You can't achieve something the cross-browser way *if there is no cross-browser way to do it*.

Comment: This solution is only for webkit browsers. Question needs crossbrowser solution and that is achievable with javascript.

Comment: FYI, this solution seems to be taken from here: http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/ which is fine, but the site explains each style (1-7) and what it applies to.

Comment: @hayk.mart mind giving any actual explanation would be helpful as this is a help forum. This is a great answer, with actual example *inside* SO. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65776078/11135092

Answer (score 16):

Your css will only work in IE browser. And the css suggessted by **hayk.mart** will olny work in webkit browsers. And by using different css hacks you can't style your browsers scroll bars with a same result.

So, it is better to use a **jQuery/Javascript** plugin to achieve a cross browser solution with a same result.

**Solution:**

By Using [**jScrollPane**](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) a jQuery plugin, you can achieve a cross browser solution

[**See This Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/tRbCs/)

Comment: The demo doesn't work at least on Chrome.

Comment: This works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65776078/11135092