# How to make body scroll bar Stylish on the right side for all browsers?

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, scrollbar

I am creating a template. I want to change the design of the body default scroll bar on right side. I want to make it stylish in such way that it will work in all browsers.

I attached a screenshot of what i want. In screenshot you will see a styled scroll bar on the right side instead of default browser scroll bar.

[image]

Please someone guide me if it is possible and how we can perform this.

Best Regards

Ayyaz

Comment: We can't read your mind. Please show us your efforts

Comment: I added a screenshot. please look at screenshot. you will get what i want.

Answer (score 1):

Try using css properties,

example:

```
body {
    scrollbar-face-color: #DBDEE7;
    scrollbar-highlight-color: #DBDEE7;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: #A4A6AB;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: #DBDEE7;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #354274;
    scrollbar-track-color: #EDEEF2;
    scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #DBDEE7;
}
```

[How to change the scrollbar color using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293275/how-to-change-the-scrollbar-color-using-css)

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hmartiro/Xck2A/1/

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much for reply. 
I tried this code but it did not work.
Also i want to see this working in all browsers.

Comment: I found an example, I'll post.

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with this example near of your goal :

http://jsfiddle.net/simurai/UsvLN/

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 7px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```