# How to change the color of the scrollbar for Microsoft Edge?

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

I want make the scrollbar for my site dark and customize it. It works on Chrome with `::-webkit-scrollbar` but it doesn't work on Edge -- I couldn't find way changing the scrollbar color on Microsoft Edge.

Does anyone know how to do this? Please help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293275/how-to-change-the-scrollbar-color-using-css

Comment: Nope. I already know about that - it doesn't work.

Comment: You'll just have to use a javascript solution.

Comment: You'll have to google that on your own. :)

Comment: Not sure why this got a down vote.  Seems like a legitimate question.

Comment: Indeed, one of the devs told me that they have removed it https://twitter.com/jonathansampson/status/627762770457432064 which is unfortunate.

Comment: It's been on the backlog almost since this question was asked... It really needs to be done. Essential for a good UX.

Answer (score 23):

There is currently no way to do this in Microsoft Edge. In IE there were vendor specific, non-standard, CSS properties to achieve this. These were removed in MS Edge as they could be used to target the browser and break compatibility with sites that were expecting old IE behaviour (the properties are very old). Unfortunately there are no good standard properties in CSS to replace these at the moment.

There is a [UserVoice suggestion](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/9081910-add-support-for-scrollbar-styling) you can vote on to add a method to style scrollbars. We use this as one of the inputs when planning feature priorities in the EdgeHTML engine.

Comment: Dear microsoft. Do us a favor.please stop developing browser apps.PLEASE!!

Comment: Currently, it does work in desktop browser, but I don't know how to make it work in their mobile app

Answer (score 4):

The following worked for me:

/* Works on Chrome, Edge, and Safari */

```
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: orange;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 3px solid orange;
}
```

For more info: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/css-scrollbars