# How to Set Scrollbar theme in XAML webview?

Tags: xaml, webview, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm creating a windows 10 xaml app. One of the views contains a webview which fetches some html.

My problem is that although the default theme on the app is set to dark, the scrollbar in the webview is always light, which jars against the rest of the UI.

I've tried setting the RequestedTheme=dark on the webview, but no joy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible since the `WebView` is based off of Edge and Edge doesn't currently support it, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31770034/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-scrollbar-for-microsoft-edge). If Edge gets this feature, you could simply insert a `STYLE` into your `head` element to define the color.

Comment: That would be hacky though since you would need to inject the style into every webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `color-scheme` in the root element!