# Edge customize scrollbar

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

Is there a way with pure css to customize Edge scrollbar like remove the arrows and color make it thinner?
I have tried using scrollbar thin or color but no luck. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution for customization. You can format this as an example:

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 1em;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}
```

You can find help here: https://css-tricks.com/the-current-state-of-styling-scrollbars/

Comment: This does not work on Edge.. @vargaadam

Comment: then read this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31770034/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-scrollbar-for-microsoft-edge @lilo

Answer (score 1):

Pure CSS is not going to work for Edge scrollbar. As according to: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-scrollbar

This hopefully will change, when Edge will use chromium engine (17ht January 2020).

You need to use JS for styling for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code to implement what your requirement is.

You can

- colour it
- make it thin or thick
- change colour or make it thin or thick on hover

as per your need

```css
.list {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 150px;
}
.list::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.5em;
}
.list::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.list::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}
.list::-webkit-scrollbar:hover {
  width: 0.7em;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
the quick brown fox jumps over little lazy dog.<br>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not work on Edge..

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way with pure css to customize Edge scrollbar like remove
>   the arrows and color make it thinner? I have tried using scrollbar
>   thin or color but no luck. Can anyone help me ?

As far as I know, currently Microsoft Edge doesn't support customize the scrollbar as you said. You could feedback this problem on Microsoft Edge Community Forum, like these links:

[Increasing Scroll-Bar Width in Windows 10 Edge](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/forum/all/increasing-scroll-bar-width-in-windows-10-edge/57da2707-9030-402f-89f4-bdbc8a2084f3)

[How to change the Microsoft Edge scrollbar color](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/how-to-change-the-microsoft-edge-scrollbar-color/a60d8a52-3e80-4ecc-b0d3-bd14293382b6?page=1).

Besides, as a temporary workaround, you could try to search some jquery custom scrollbar plugin, such as [SimpleBar](https://grsmto.github.io/simplebar/) and [Custom Scrollbar Plugins](https://www.jqueryscript.net/blog/Best-Custom-Scroll-Bar-jQuery-Plugins.html).