# Change Color of the Scrolling Bar in Iframe

Tags: css, iframe

I wonder if you can change the colour of the horizontal scrolling tab in iframe? Please let me know if you think that such effect can be achieved in all browsers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293275/how-to-change-the-scrollbar-color-using-css

Comment: thank you! you think the plugin thy suggest will work in all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

As [hayk.mart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901553/hayk-mart) said in the link that [DiegoS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5555200/diegos) sent, you use the `::-webkit-scrollbar` selector like so:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar              { /* 1 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-button       { /* 2 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-track        { /* 3 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece  { /* 4 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb        { /* 5 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner       { /* 6 */ }
::-webkit-resizer                { /* 7 */ }
```

Comment: thank you for your reply...do I add this code as Javascript?

Comment: No @Gabriel, this is CSS.