# Webkit and Mozilla altering of the scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scrollbar color change in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890471/scrollbar-color-change-in-firefox)

I'm currently using `::-webkit-scrollbar` and `::-webkit-scrollbar-track` to alter the scrollbar style, but I know that doesn't show up on Firefox. I have tried replacing webkit with moz, but that didn't do anything.

I have tried jQuery, but it's very hard to implement on site with the other jquery mods etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent of that webkit psuedo selector for any other browser. The only alternative is javascript/jQuery based.

For example, [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html).