# Scrollbars in mozilla

Tags: html, css, firefox, scrollbar

I have been using chrome for the longest time of my life. When I made my website and wanted to hide a scrollbar that appeared in my sidebar menu, I just used `overflow: auto;` in CSS, and then `.sidebar_menu::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none;}`. So there was no visible scrollbar, and I could scroll through the sidebar menu with my mouse wheel.

Yesterday, I started using Mozilla Firefox, and I realized that the scrollbar is vidible, and `.sidebar_menu::-moz-scrollbar {display: none;}` didn't work. This scared me to be honest, as I cannot see a way to get out of this. I just want it to be the same in chrome and Mozilla. At least this scrollbar thing.

Comment: You can try to get this library. It's a custom scroll js library and might help you. http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll

Comment: There's nothing like that for Firefox. Or IE, or Edge, or anything non-webkit. Safest bet would be to overflow:hidden the element, then use javascript to adjust the (negative) margin-top on scroll

Comment: There is no fix, can oonly hack this one --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580366/hide-scrollbar-in-firefox

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since [Firefox 64](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/64), is possible to use [new specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scrollbars) for a simple Scrollbar styling (*not as complete as in Chrome with vendor prefixes*).

In [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/ldetomi/4Lt2ro5z/6/) is possible to see a solution that combine different rules to address both Firefox and Chrome with a similar (not equal) final result:

The key rules are:

**For Firefox**

```
.scroller {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scrollbar-color: red green;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
}
```

**For Chrome**

```
.scroller::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    background-color: green;
}

.scroller::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 8px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.scroller::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

In the example linked are used also additional styles for Chrome to improve final style (such as rounded corners and shadows)

Answer (score 1):

The scrollbar (normally) can't be modified. This is up to the browsers to handle how it will look like.

But, you can do it because of **vendor prefixes**. Those are prefixes you use that target specific browsers, such as

- `-o-` for Opera
- `-moz-` for Mozilla
- `-webkit-` for Safari, Chrome, Android ...
- `-ms-` for IE and Edge

You were right to try it, unfortunately there's no equivalent for Mozilla. You can **[take a look at this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox)** to try to find a solution, but honestly, you should just give up, almost no one is paying attention to that ...

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone stumbles across this, you can easily achieve the same effect in Firefox using:

```css
.sidebar_menu {
    overflow: auto;
    scrollbar-width: none; /* hide the scrollbar in FF */
}
```

As stated by the other answers, FF currently only supports `scrollbar-width: thin|none` and `scrollbar-color: #fgcolor #bgcolor` without any pseudo CSS selectors or vendor prefixes. A cross-browser solution would be:

```css
 /* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
.sidebar_menu::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
.sidebar_menu {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
    scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it fully addresses OP question

Answer (score 0):

I believe that -webkit-scrollbar is not supported in Firefox.
Although you can look for javascript libraries, which will do what you need.